# Show that $\operatorname{rank} A = 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Matrix $A \in R^{3, 2015}$ is given. It is known that matrix $AA^{T}$ is invertible. Show that $\operatorname{rank} A = 3$.

How to start this? What does the info that $AA^{T}$ is invertible gives us?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain me the notation $R^{3, 2015}$? What does it express?

Comment: @Dac0 I assume $R^{3,2015}$ stands for $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 2015}$, the matrices vector space with $3$ rows and $2015$ columns with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ok thanks, for the matrix space I was used to a different notation such as $M^3_{2015}( \mathbb R )$ so it was a bit confusing

Comment: @Dac0 In France, we use a similar notation to yours, namely $\mathcal{M}_{3,2015}(\mathbb{R})$, but it seems $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 2015}$ is the international notation.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A^\intercal A$ is an invertible matrix of order $3$, one has: $$\textrm{rank}(A^\intercal A)=3.$$
Besides, one has: $$\textrm{rank}(A^\intercal A)\leqslant\min\left(\textrm{rank}(A),\textrm{rank}\left(^\intercal A\right)\right).$$
But, one has: $$\textrm{rank}\left(^\intercal A\right)=\textrm{rank}(A).$$
Therefore, one gets: $$3\leqslant\textrm{rank}(A).$$
Hence the result, since the number of lines of a matrix is greater than its rank.
(Edited)

*Remark.* Using $\textrm{rank}(AB)\leqslant\min(\textrm{rank}(A),\textrm{rank}(B))$ is overkill, instead you can just use $\textrm{rank}(AB)\leqslant\textrm{rank}(B)$, which is an easier result to prove.